# Swift nested functions vs Closure Variables

Tags: swift

I want to make a function that fetches a record from CloudKit, if it encounters a temporary network error the function should retry.

```
func fetchRecord(withRecordID recordID: CKRecordID, returnBlock: (optError: ErrorType?) -> Void){

    func internalReturnBlock(optError optError: ErrorType?){
        if NSThread.isMainThread() {
            returnBlock(optError: optError)
        }
        else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                returnBlock(optError: optError)
            })
        }
    }

    func internalWork(){
        privateDB.fetchRecordWithID(recordID) { (optRecord, optError) in
            if let error = optError{
                // IF NETWORK ERROR RETRY
                internalWork()
            }
            else{
                internalReturnBlock(optError: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    internalWork()
}
```

Here I define such function (simplified), If the fetch encounters an error it retries by calling the nested function internalWork()

My question is what would be the difference between using nested functions or creating local closure variables?
For example, here I change the internalReturnBlock to a closure variable:

```
func fetchRecord2(withRecordID recordID: CKRecordID, returnBlock: (optError: ErrorType?) -> Void){

    var internalReturnBlock = { (optError: NSError?) in
        if NSThread.isMainThread() {
            returnBlock(optError: optError)
        }
        else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                returnBlock(optError: optError)
            })
        }
    }

    func internalWork(){
        privateDB.fetchRecordWithID(recordID) { (optRecord, optError) in
            if let error = optError{
                // IF NETWORK ERROR RETRY
                internalWork()
            }
            else{
                internalReturnBlock(nil)
            }
        }
    }


    internalWork()
}
```

What are the differences between using a nested function vs a variable block?
Any advantages or problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference in effect. One is a declared function with a name, the other is anonymous. But they are both functions. And a function is a closure in Swift, so they are both closures.

An anonymous function is permitted to use some abbreviations of form, such as the omission of `return` in a one-liner that returns a value. But none of those abbreviations makes any ultimate effective difference.

However, an anonymous function in Swift has one feature a declared function does not — a capture list. This can help avoid retain cycles.

```
f {
    [unowned self] in
    return self.name
}
```

Also, an anonymous function is defined after the declaration of the function that takes it as a parameter, so it can use terms that appear in that declaration:

```
f(param:String) {
    return param
}
```

But if you are not using those features, then it doesn't matter which you use. They work identically.

Comment: Reading my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions Notice that my motivation for switching from declared functions to anonymous functions is basically just that the names are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!, I also just found out that the closure variable cannot call on itself at least the way Im declaring it, so internalWork() must stay as a nested func.

Comment: Good point! There are ways around that limitation; however, I'm not so sure your recursion is such a great idea. What if we are never able to get through? You will eventually have yourself a real-life stack overflow.

Comment: yes you are right, the recursion must have a retryLimit. :)